# Adding a LIMIT 1 to a simple MySQL Query causes it to hang

Tags: mysql, limit

I have a strange issue where by adding `LIMIT 1` to a query, it causes the query to never return. And yet, when I remove that `LIMIT 1` the query works instantly. `LIMIT 1` should typically speed things up, not slow them down, so I'm wondering what I'm missing here.

The query that works fine is this:

### Hangs For Infinite

```sql
SELECT 
    `groups`.*
FROM 
    `groups` 
INNER JOIN 
    `positions`
ON 
    `groups`.`uid` = `positions`.`group_uid`
WHERE 
    `positions`.`component_uid` = '1234' 
    AND 
    (`groups`.deleted_at IS NULL)     
    AND 
    (`positions`.deleted_at IS NULL)
LIMIT 
    1
```

**Associated `EXPLAIN` Result:**

```sql
id select_type table     type possible_keys                 key                           key_len ref   rows  Extra
1  SIMPLE      groups    ALL  index_groups_on_deleted_at    NULL                          NULL    NULL  6832  Using where
1  SIMPLE      positions ref  index_positions_on_deleted_at index_positions_on_deleted_at 6       const 22110 Using index condition; Using where
```

### Works Just Fine

```sql
SELECT 
    `groups`.*
FROM 
    `groups` 
INNER JOIN 
    `positions`
ON 
    `groups`.`uid` = `positions`.`group_uid` 
WHERE
    `positions`.`component_uid` = '1234' 
    AND 
    (`groups`.deleted_at IS NULL)     
    AND 
    (`positions`.deleted_at IS NULL)
/* LIMIT 
    1 */
```

**Associated `EXPLAIN` Result:**

```sql
id select_type table     type possible_keys                 key   key_len ref   rows  Extra
1  SIMPLE      groups    ALL  index_groups_on_deleted_at    NULL  NULL    NULL  6832  Using where
1  SIMPLE      positions ALL  index_positions_on_deleted_at NULL  NULL    NULL  44220 Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
```

**CREATE TABLE Commands:**

```sql
CREATE TABLE `groups` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `deleted_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_groups_on_deleted_at` (`deleted_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6941 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `positions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `component_uid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `deleted_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `routing_group_uid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_positions_on_deleted_at` (`deleted_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=44321 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

But there's no errors produced so I can't figure out what could be going wrong.

Any ideas on what the issue could be would be great.

Thanks.

### Update

From comments that:

> Mysql [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/is-null-optimization.html) mentions the use of `IS NULL` for optimization that it can handles only one.

**This still hangs:**

```sql
SELECT 
    `groups`.*
FROM 
    `groups` 
INNER JOIN 
    `positions`
ON 
    `groups`.`uid` = `positions`.`group_uid`
WHERE 
    `positions`.`component_uid` = '1234' 
    /* AND 
    (`groups`.deleted_at IS NULL) */
    AND 
    (`positions`.deleted_at IS NULL)
LIMIT 
    1
```

**But this works fine:**

```sql
SELECT 
    `groups`.*
FROM 
    `groups` 
INNER JOIN 
    `positions`
ON 
    `groups`.`uid` = `positions`.`group_uid`
WHERE 
    `positions`.`component_uid` = '1234' 
    AND 
    (`groups`.deleted_at IS NULL)     
    /* AND 
    (`positions`.deleted_at IS NULL) */
LIMIT 
    1
```

Comment: Add `Explain ` before the query and show us what is says with and without the `LIMIT`

Comment: You got it. Gimme two seconds.

Comment: Are you using a graphical client? If yes, which one?

Comment: as  a sidenote why is your `deleted_at` column name not wrapped in backticks as you've done for all the others?

Comment: @JorgeCampos I'm using Sequel Pro, yes. But when running the raw SQL query via Ruby on Rails, I'm getting the same result.

Comment: @Martin Yeah, that bugs me too but that's how Ruby on Rails (v3.2 anyway) spits out their MySQL. No idea why it doesn't use backticks for the column names. I'm sure the newer versions do now.

Comment: @Martin `component_uid` isn't an integer value, it's a unique hash we generate so we use a `VARCHAR(255)` for that.

Comment: Could you also add a `CREATE TABLE` output showing the creation data for the table? Particularly indexes. Cheers

Comment: @JoshPinter ah ok `:-)`

Comment: @Martin Okay, added CREATE TABLE Commands.

Comment: Mysql [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/is-null-optimization.html) mention the use of `IS NULL` for optimization that it can handles only one. So try changing both queries a bit add in you on clause `and \`groups\`.deleted_at = \`positions\`.deleted_at` and remove one of then of the where clause and try it again please.

Comment: Why is LIMIT not blue in this code sample? Or is that just me?

Comment: @Lexib0y It's not just you. Looks black to me as well.

Comment: Positions is the table if more rows right and it is the one hanging, can you drop that index and reacreate it? `alter table positions drop index index_positions_on_deleted_at` and `create index index_positions_on_deleted_at on positions(deleted_at);` and see what happens? I'm thinking in some sort of problem on the index file.

Comment: @Lexib0y Something to do with the previous comment I think, I've seen it happen here in SO.

Comment: Maybe the guys on http://dba.stackexchange.com can have a better though on this...

Comment: @JorgeCampos Yes, that's correct. I'm thinking you might be right. I'll reindex it and post back the result...

Comment: @JorgeCampos Tried deleting and re-creating the index but same hanging result. **However**, if I delete the index and re-run the query without re-creating that index it works fine. WTF.

Comment: Is there anything else running on these tables? Or is just your query? I wonder if something is happening with that field on the positions table, some kind of concurrency lock or lock for update

Comment: @JorgeCampos No, this is shown both locally in the development environment and on the production server.

Comment: @Martin A) Do you have a link for the documentation around only one `IS NULL` being allowed, and B) That doesn't explain why it works when removing the index on deleted_at or when commenting the `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: @JoshPinter you maybe want to ask that to Jorge. Who links to documentation.